# LOV in detail block

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I am facing a problem in Oracle Forms. I have a master block and a detail block. Both in a different tab. In my master block I have a LOV, no problem here, works fine. Now I am trying to pop up a LOV in my detail block. But no success here.

At first it showed with all possible values for the detail, disregarding the choice made in the master block. Turned out to be a mistake in my master-detail relation. Made some changes on my master-detail relation and now it 's simply not showing. But I can browse the correct records using the arrows.

Can someone point me out what could be wrong?

In addition I could use a good online tutorial that goes beyond displaying a record.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your problem is, but - on the LOV do you have `Automatic Refresh` set to `Yes`? If not, it will only execute the query to populate the LOV the first time it is opened.